# Shutil.copy2 is throwing out a filenotfound error for destination folder?

Tags: python

I have been working with the same script for a while and it used to work perfectly fine up until today it stopped working. My script basically prefills certain word templates and moves them to a destination folder. Here is the line of code that is the problem:

```
shutil.copy2(os.path.join(template_locations[0], file_name), os.path.join(new_path, new_file_name))
```

I have verified that the source folder location and file name exist (template_locations[0], file_name). the destination folder also exist (new_path) and is actually created by the script in an earlier function. I am changing the file name to new_file_name but it shouldn't be an issued. before it would just save the file under the new name in the destination folder.

what changed or what is wrong with the callout?